# My window with tkinter immediately closes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a program that tells whether a given person's age is smoking age. I was able to make it work in the command line but I decided I wanted to make an actual windowed program. http://pastebin.com/0HettMLx is my current code.

```
import random
import sys
import os
import time
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox, Label, Button, StringVar


age=StringVar

window = tkinter. Tk()#creates a new window
window.title("Are you old enough to smoke?")#title
window.geometry("300x200")#window size
window.wm_iconbitmap('favicon.ico')#icon

photo=tkinter.PhotoImage(file="images.png")#picture in said window
w=tkinter.Label(window, image=photo)
w.pack()

lbl=tkinter.Label(window, text="Please enter your age.", bg="light salmon", fg="blue2")#label text & color
lbl.pack()

ent=tkinter.Entry(window, text="(Your age here)", textvariable=age)
ent.pack()

def callback():
   button_pressed=True
   while True:
       if (age) >= 18:
            print('You are legally able to smoke.')
       else:
            print("You are not of legal age to smoke.")

       if (age)>= 18:
            print ("You are legally able to smoke cigarettes.")
       if (age)>=21:
            print("You are legally able to smoke marijuana.")
       if (age)>=40:
            print("You're above the age of forty,\nDo you really need to ask if you're old enough?")
       if (age)<=12:
            print("You're to young to smoke get out of here.")

btn=tkinter.Button(window, text="Confirm", bg="sienna1", fg="blue2", relief="groove", command=callback())
btn.pack()

window.configure(background='light salmon')#back ground

window.mainloop()# draws window
```

But every time I go to run it the window opens but immediately closes. It worked fine with just displaying the button, label, and entry but once I started trying to implement the command=callback into the button it doesn't work. I just want to know how to fix it closing.

Running python34, win7-64bit.

Comment: You should include the code on this post (click the Edit link).

Comment: I honestly would, but I am not to sure how to. That is what the pastebin link is for.

Comment: After you click the Edit link, paste the code in the text box, select that code, and click "{ }", which indents it so that Stack Overflow recognizes it's a code block.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign a callback to a button, you need to assign the callable. `command=callback()` is assigning what `callback()` returns (`None`) to the command, instead set `command=callback`:

```
btn=tkinter.Button(window, text="Confirm", bg="sienna1", fg="blue2", relief="groove", command=callback)
```

Your program is probably crashing because you're trying to access `age` by just simply referencing it like a normal variable, StringVars are a little different.  To get the value of a StringVar you need to call `get()` on it.  You'll also need to properly initialize the StringVar, using `StringVar()` instead of just `StringVar`.  You also need to do this **after** the call to `Tk()`:

```
window = tkinter.Tk()  # creates a new window
age = StringVar()  # you need to call this after the line above
```

Finally, in your callback you need to properly access the value of the StringVar and convert it to an integer, this is easiest done at the top of the callback by defining a new variable to hold the integer and then replacing `age`.  There also is no need to have a `while True:` loop in this callback, especially since you never `break` out of it:

```
def callback():
    ageint = int(age.get())
    button_pressed=True

    #  Remove while True: loop and fix indentation below

    if (ageint) >= 18:     # Replace all "age" with "ageint" from here on
        print('You are legally able to smoke.')
    ....
```

Comment: So after reading through and changing things as needed I attempted to run the program. It opened the window fine but when you enter an age it says
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Josh/Documents/Trial Python Programs/Smoke window Program.py", line 25, in callback
    age=age.get()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'age' referenced before assignment

Comment: @JoshuaDay See my edit above, I noticed a few other things that needed to be changed in the callback

Comment: It is working now thank you! Now to figure out how to make the messages appear in a message box. But I will atleast attempt to figure that out on my own first (I think it is more fun that way). Thank you a TON!

Comment: @JoshuaDay Glad I could help, and good luck! You seem to be well on track.

Answer (score 1):

I modify code, and add a comment "**modify**" identifying show my changed code.
see it:

```
import random
import sys
import os
import time
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox, Label, Button, StringVar

window = tkinter.Tk()  # creates a new window
window.title("Are you old enough to smoke?")  # title
window.geometry("300x200")  # window size

# modify: comment it,because no ico on my computer
# window.wm_iconbitmap('favicon.ico')  # icon
# photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="images.png")  # picture in said window


w = tkinter.Label(window)
w.pack()

lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="Please enter your age.", bg="light salmon", fg="blue2")  # label text & color
lbl.pack()

# modify: del textvariable method, use get() method to catch text 
ent = tkinter.Entry(window, text="(Your age here)")
ent.pack()


def callback():
    # modify:  use get() to get text,  
    age = ent.get()
    # modify: check all is  numbers
    if str(age).isdigit():
        age = int(age)
        if age <= 12:
            print("You're to young to smoke get out of here.")
        elif (age) >= 40:
            print("You're above the age of forty,\nDo you really need to ask if you're old enough?")
        elif (age) >= 21:
            print("You are legally able to smoke marijuana.")
        elif (age) >= 18:
            print("You are legally able to smoke cigarettes.")
    else:
        print('the age is not number')


#modify: callback() change to callback
btn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Confirm", bg="sienna1", fg="blue2", relief="groove", command=callback)
btn.pack()

window.configure(background='light salmon')  

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Posting without posting an explanation isn't very helpful. Without a description of the changes we have to read the code line by line, character by character and compare it to the original code.

Comment: @BryanOakley : code is changed to add comment .  please, thank you .